# How to check for presence of the key of a value (as defined in one dict) in another dict, in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, set, key

Given a mapping dict `mapping`:

```
{
'John': 'A',
'Mary': 'B',
'Tim' :'C'
}
```

I am then provided a dict `spend`:

```
{
'John': 23,
'Mary': 1,
}
```

and a dict `revenue`:

```
{
'A': 12,
'B': 2,
'C': 23
}
```

then:

```
for k, v in spend.items():
# do stuff
```

Within this loop, I want to check if **an entry in `revenue` does not have a corresponding entry in `spend`** (based on our mapping). One such example is Tim (because 'C' is present in `revenue`, but 'Tim' is not present in `spend`).

An approach of looping again (within this `for` loop) - this time over `revenue.keys()` and checking that the key is not in `spend.keys()` - unfortunately is not an option as this will result in `len(revenue)` number of duplicates, per match.

How do we achieve the desired reverse checking without a loop?

Comment: for clarification: the `mapping` dict is static. The `spend` and `mapping` dicts will each day contain differing data.

Comment: Do you have to loop through spend? If you can loop through mapping then it can be done in one line: [k for k,v in mapping.items() if not spend.get(k) and revenue.get(v)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily if you reverse your keys and values in the `mapping` dictionary and then loop over revenue dicitonary. You do not need to permanently reverse it, just reverse it and store in a new dictionary before you do the loop.

Example -

```
reversedmapping = {v:k for k,v in mapping.items()}
for k,v in revenue.items():
    if (k not in reversedmapping) or (reversedmapping[k] not in spend):
        print(k)
```

Comment: Nicely done, Anand. It's working well, but now I have to test that **both** conditions are true, and I'm encountering the is problem. Any thoughts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331029/why-does-a-keyerror-get-thrown-in-logical-and-but-not-in-a-logical-or#31331059

Comment: So do you want to not print `k` when a `key` in revenue dict is not found as a value in `mapping`?