# Why does a KeyError get thrown in logical AND but not in a logical OR

Tags: python, boolean-logic

I have a certain string `k` that may or many not a key of a dict `reversedmapping`, and another dict `spendDict` where it may also be a key.

Why does the following check succeed (i.e. run to completion), for a value of k that is not a key of `reversedmapping`:

```
if (k not in reversedmapping) or (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)
```

whereas I get a `KeyError` (for k) when I change it to logical AND:

`if (k not in reversedmapping) and (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)`:

And how do I rewrite the AND variant to avoid the KeyError?

Comment: Of course, I want both checks to succeed, but I'm surprised that a `KeyError` isn't thrown for *both*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `(k not in reversedmapping)` is `True`, then

```
(k not in reversedmapping) or (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)
```

[*short-circuits*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2580136/190597), which means it returns `True` without evaluating

```
(reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)
```

Since `True or anything` is `True`.

In contrast,

```
 (k not in reversedmapping) and (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)
```

must evaluate both parts before Python can determine that the total expression
is `True`.

---

If `(k not in reversedmapping)` is `True`, then `reversedmapping[k]` will raise
`KeyError`.

If `(k not in reversedmapping)` is `False`, then the expression short-circuits
and returns `False` since `False and anything` is `False`.

So

```
(k not in reversedmapping) and (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)
```

will always either return `False` or raise a `KeyError`. There is no situation
under which it could return `True`. *Both conditions can not be True.*

Comment: I see. Is the only way to handle this then to flip this around and put a try/except around `reversedmapping[k] in spendDict`, and if I get a KeyError, pass `True` to the rest of the expression?

Comment: Uh, I'd just leave out the `and (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)`. If k in reversed mapping, the statement is already false. If k not in reversed mapping, then clearly reversedmapping[k] is not in spendDict, given that it doesn't exist, so the whole statement is true. Therefore, there is no need to check the second half of the statement at all. @Pyderman

Comment: @Pyderman,  `(k not in reversedmapping) and (reversedmapping[k] not in spendDict)` is always either `False` or a `KeyError`. There is no case when this expression could by `True`. When do you want it to be `True`?

Comment: So some context: most (but not all) of the `keys` of `spendDict` will actually be the `values` of `reversedmapping` (and vice-versa). See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260579/how-to-check-for-presence-of-the-key-of-a-value-as-defined-in-one-dict-in-anot for more context. Both checks are required.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen both checks are required (see one comment up).

Answer (score 2):

Python's `and` and `or` are [short-circuit operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). That means they only evaluate both parts of the expression when the answer isn't clear from the left hand operand. For `and`, if the first operand evaluates to `False`, then there's no way the result can be true, so the second operand isn't evaluated. For `or`, it's the opposite - if the first operand evaluates to `True`, the result is `True` no matter what the second operand is.

In your case, if `k` isn't in `reversedmapping`, `or` sees a true value on its left hand side and returns without evaluating the right hand sids, so no `KeyError`. If you use an `and` and the first test is true (`k` is not in `reversedmapping`), it's still forced to evaluate the second operand to see if they're both true, so it tries to pull `k` from the dict and throws an exception.

Comment: OK. See my reply to @HappyLeapSecond. Is there a better way of writing this than reversing the logic with a try/except?

Comment: I've read your question a few times and I'm not sure I understand why the `or` based check is not sufficient. So you have three cases:

1. k is in reverseMapping, reverseMapping[k] is in spendDict
2. k is in reverseMapping, reverseMapping[k] is NOT in spendDict
3. k is NOT in reverseMapping, reverseMapping[k] does NOT exist

The check with the `or` covers all of these cases. (sorry that comments have no line formatting)

Comment: @ See here for some background, and let's imagine that `reversedmapping` above is the {k,v} for v,k in `mapping`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260579/how-to-check-for-presence-of-the-key-of-a-value-as-defined-in-one-dict-in-anot

Comment: Yes, that is what I assumed. Perhaps it would help if you would write out the cases for which you want the `if` and `else` blocks to be evaluated (e.g. "in these two cases I want the `if` block to be run. In these other cases I want the `else` block run)

Comment: How about: if `reversedmapping.get(k)` is not `None`, then go check if the returned value is in spendDict?

Comment: So:             if reversedmapping.get(k) is not None:
                if (k not in reversedmapping) and (reversedmapping.get(k) not in spendDict):

Comment: That should read *if reversedmapping.get(k) is None:
                if (k not in reversedmapping) and (reversedmapping.get(k) not in spendDict): *

Comment: `reversedmapping.get(k) is None` is equivalent to `k not in reversedmapping` unless you have explicitly set `reversedmapping[k] = None`. As I suggested above I think you need to go back and think about what you're really trying to test for here. I still am not sure you have a clear picture of this based on the responses I'm getting.